# M2E not installed while starting eclipse luna

Tags: maven, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin, centos, m2e

Whenever i am closing my spring boot project in eclipse luna(4.4.2) . Eclipse says "M2E(maven for eclipse ) not installed". but Maven for eclipse is already installed. Even eclipse is not able to create  spring starter project. Please comment/reply if anyone has any clue or has faced same issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use the update site of m2e to reinstall it? Maybe the installation is broken.

Comment: Yes, reinstalled it multiple times. Still same issue.

Comment: If you install a virgin eclipse Luna, you still get this issue? Or does your project require a newer version of m2e? Have you tried with Eclipse Mars or Neon?

Comment: remove maven nature and again configure-->convert to maven project

Comment: Thanks Ali, I removed maven and configured again. it started working.